# How to prevent same task name for multiple DAG runs to not collide?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Using Airflow 1.10.3, our DAGs run once everyday. But sometimes, if it spills over, it results in collision of tasks, leading to failure.

Even though the tasks belong to different DAG runs, but since the task name is the same, it results in failure.

```
[2021-07-27 11:49:09,642] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [<TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-24 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>, <TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-26 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>]
[2021-07-27 11:49:09,642] {logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2021-07-27 11:49:09,642] {airflow_utils.py:114} INFO - Found existing tasks running with state RUNNING - [<TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-24 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>, <TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-26 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>]. Therefore skipping this task instance
[2021-07-27 11:49:09,644] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - Found existing tasks running with state RUNNING - [<TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-24 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>, <TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-26 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>]. Therefore skipping this task instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models/__init__.py", line 1441, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/airflow/dags/utils/airflow_utils.py", line 115, in execute
    raise RuntimeError(error)
RuntimeError: Found existing tasks running with state RUNNING - [<TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-24 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>, <TaskInstance: dag1.part1.task1 2021-07-26 05:30:00+00:00 [running]>]. Therefore skipping this task instance
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The primary key for TaskInstances is a compound PK of the dag's id, the task's id and the execution date of the DAG, so I believe your problem is not collision of names in task instances. Can you provide more information? Perhaps the DAG file

Answer (score 1):

Based on this entry in the log:

`ERROR - Found existing tasks running with state RUNNING ... Therefore skipping this task instance`

I suspect you have `max_active_runs` or `max_active_runs_per_dag`  set to 1. If you need or expect multiple runs of the DAG to execute concurrently you can increase that number accordingly.